# Python, why print nothing with print function, is there any wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there any problems? when I use `print` function, sometimes it works, however, sometimes not. I am confused. the following is my code, and is typing in jupyter notebook(ipython), every variables have defined before, there is no matter with variables. there is also no error output. but no result neither.

```
from __future__ import print_function

print("Top terms per cluster:")
print()
#sort cluster centers by proximity to centroid
order_centroids = km.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1] 

for i in range(num_clusters):
    print("Cluster %d words:" % i, end='')

    for ind in order_centroids[i, :6]: #replace 6 with n words per cluster
        print(' %s' % vocab_frame.ix[terms[ind].split(' ')].values.tolist()[0][0].encode('utf-8', 'ignore'), end=',')

    print() #add whitespace
    print() #add whitespace

    print("Cluster %d labels:" % i, end='')
    for title in frame.ix[i]['label'].values.tolist():
        print(' %s,' % title, end='')
    print() #add whitespace
    print() #add whitespace
```

Comment: Which times and in what way does it work, and which times and in what way does it not work?

Comment: Your example code does not run. `num_clusters` is not defined.

Comment: Its printing till second print method `print()` and after that its not working bcoz `km` not defined and `num_clusters` is also not defined.

Comment: which `print()` doesn't work ? inside `for` ? maybe `for` has no elements to print.

Comment: there is no result for these codes, and I have defined the 'num_clusters' **bold** 'code' and 'km' **bold** 'code' before. so there is no matter with these two variables.

Comment: there is no result for these codes, and I have defined the 'num_clusters' **bold** 'code' and 'km' **bold** 'code' before. so there is no matter with these two variables.  none of print in these codes works anything, though the print("Top terms per cluster") also does not work

Comment: and I have tried to print ("hello world"), there is also no output.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jupyter notebook, but for example pycharm on the key shortcut runs the last runned file, which may lead to situations like that, where there is no output, where it should be (eg. working on the other file and pressing shift+F10 to run it).
Are you sure, that you run exactly this code? Or running anything at all?

Comment: e ,there is also no output. I am sure I run exactly this code.